# Lucene TokenFilter: How to recognize the last token from TokenStream?

Tags: lucene, token

For Lucene, I want to do some processing only on the last token of the tokenStream with tokenFilter. For example, given sentence "hello my world", only apply my processing to "world", not other tokens.

I can do by iterating the entire input of tokenStream first in order to get the offset of the last token, and then re-starting from the first token. Because I already know the offset of the last token, I can recognize whether the current token is a last token or not.

However, since looping twice is inefficient for sure, I want to do it with iterating tokenStream only once, but it seems like hard to find right way.

For example, suppose MyFilter looks like: (Sure, this MyFilter is basic structure of the TokenFilter).

```
public class MyFilter extends TokenFilter{

    public MyFilter(TokenStream input){
        super(input);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        if (input.incrementToken()){

            /*
                if(current token is the last token):
                    Want to apply something only to the last token.
            */

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How to recognize if the current token is the last one or not?

Answer (score 0):

I may well have got the wrong end of the stick here, but I think the idea of a ***stream*** is precisely that you may well be able to tell where it starts but that it's much more tricky to know where it ends... which is probably why they called it a `Token*Stream*`.

`TokenFilter` can tell you when the stream starts: you just have to override `reset()`.

There is a method `TokenFilter.end()`, of course, and you could try overriding that, but Javadoc says:

> This method is called by the consumer after the last token has been
>   consumed, after TokenStream.incrementToken() returned false (using the
>   new TokenStream API).

... which probably means its output has already been used by the "consumer" by then.

To detect the end I think you'd have to re-engineer your `Tokenizer`.  Just looking at `StandardTokenizer`, for example, and its "business end" `StandardTokenizerImpl`, this might be quite involved. No doubt better to make your own simple `Tokeniser`: it accepts `Strings`, or whatever, and the way to proceed would be to tokenise before spewing out the tokens to the filter(s).  You would know how many tokens were going to be spewed out, and (for example) you'd make this number available to your `TokenFilter` at any one time...